# ur_robot_driver: test_move.py keeps on "waiting for server..."

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, ros-kinetic, universal-robots

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, i wish i could run the script "test_move.py" included in the package the same way it was done with ur_modern_driver. My ROS version is Kinetic and i'm using Ubuntu 16.04. Actually working with the simulator URSim, no physical robot tested.

these were the steps i made:

`$roscore`

`$roslaunch ur_robot_driver ur5_bringup.launch robot_ip:=127.0.0.1 kinematics_config:=/home/bruno/my_robot_calibration.yaml`

`rosrun ur_robot_driver test_move.py`

after running the last command, i get "Waiting for server" and nothing happens...

in another terminal i put `$rqt_graph` and as i guessed, the test_move node is connected to nothing.

[image: rosgraph2]

I'm not sure what I can do next...

Thank you in advance for your time and help

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/344391/ur_robot_driver:-test_move.py-keeps-on-%22waiting-for-server...%22/) by [brodwix](https://answers.ros.org/users/51863/brodwix/) on ROS Answers with karma: 45 on 2020-02-17

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-02-18**:\

> i wish i could run the script "test_move.py" included in the package the same way it was done with ur_modern_driver

please clarify: `UniversalRobots/Universal_Robots_ROS_Driver` does not provide any `test_move.py`, so I'm not sure what you're saying here.

**Comment by [Wifi-cable](https://answers.ros.org/users/51566/wifi-cable/) on 2020-02-18**:
-Does your test_move.py use the move comander (like the the moveIT tutorials?)
-do you have the fmauch branch with the moveIT configurations of the Universal_robots driver?
(or are you using the  deprecated ur_modern driver? )

If so i suggest launching the  robot, than either the demo,

```
roslaunch ur5_moveit_config demo.launch
```

or alternately the move group:

```
roslaunch ur5_moveit_config move_group.launch
```

than run your python script

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-02-18**:
@Wifi-cable: `ur_robot_driver` and `ur_modern_driver` use different names for the action servers. That's most likely why OP has the script just sitting there "waiting for controllers". `test_move.py` was not written for `ur_robot_driver` (it's also not included with it), hence the mismatch.

> If so i suggest launching the robot, than either the demo,

`demo.launch` (or actually: the nodes it starts) doesn't interact with `ur_hardware_interface`, so I'm not sure how starting it would help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hello and thank you both for your answers,

> please clarify:
> UniversalRobots/Universal_Robots_ROS_Driver
> does not provide any test_move.py, so
> I'm not sure what you're saying here.

@gvdhoorn, sorry, i forgot to mention that i moved the script "test_move.py" from fmauch_universal_robot package to Universal_Robots_ROS_Driver package in order to run it.

The solution i found yesterday was changing line 94 on "test_move.py"

(https://github.com/fmauch/universal_robot/blob/kinetic-devel/ur_driver/test_move.py)

from

```
‘follow_joint_trajectory’
```

to

```
'scaled_pos_traj_controller/follow_joint_trajectory'
```

that made the robot to run the script.
I guess this is because of the names given for the action servers like @gvdhoorn said or posibbly because of the way the robot is controlled now (via ExternalControl URCap)

this is the graph result i got.
[image: rosgraph3]

---

Originally posted by [brodwix](https://answers.ros.org/users/51863/brodwix/) with karma: 45 on 2020-02-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Vuro H](https://answers.ros.org/users/52882/vuro-h/) on 2020-04-19**:
Hi @brodwix, great you got this working. I'm currently trying to do the same thing but having the same problems. Unfortunately your fix didn't work for me. Would it be possible for you to share your repo layout (or even to where exactly you copied the test_move.py) so that I might be able to fix mine. Thanks in advance!

**Comment by [brodwix](https://answers.ros.org/users/51863/brodwix/) on 2020-04-21**:
Hello, sorry for the late response... i just copied "test_move.py" from fmauch_universal_robot package to Universal_Robots_ROS_Driver package...

my layout back then was just this:

```
catkin_ws
-build
-devel
-src
 -fmaucn_universal_robot (copy "test_move.py" from here)
 -Universal_Robots_ROS_Driver
    - ...
    - test_move.py
```

After this, i changed line 94 and that did the trick ;)

I'm actually working with Ubuntu 19.04 and  ROS Melodic because the Universal_Robots_ROS_Driver repo recommended this... but you can still work with Kinetic (for me is the best option, because URSim is not compatible with Ubuntu 19.04.

Good Luck!

**Comment by [nullspace](https://answers.ros.org/users/57539/nullspace/) on 2020-11-02**:
i did the same still it is showing the same error "waitng for server     ...")

1.
catkin_ws
-build
-devel
-src
-fmaucn_universal_robot (copy "test_move.py" from here)
-Universal_Robots_ROS_Driver
- ...
- test_move.py

mine same as above layout
changed the line but not working

```
"def main():
global client
try:
    rospy.init_node("test_move", anonymous=True, disable_signals=True)
    client = actionlib.SimpleActionClient('scaled_pos_traj_controller/follow_joint_trajectory', FollowJointTrajectoryAction)
    print "Waiting for server..."
```

above is the part of the python code i changed